I am given a programming prompt that I am having trouble figuring out the constructor and parameter part on
this question is in C++.
So, here's the prompt:
write a full class definition for a class named GasTank, and contains the members:

data member named amount of type double
A constructor that accepts no parameters:The constructor initializes data member amount to 0.
A function named addGas that accepts a parameter of type double.The value of the amount instance variable is increase
d by the value of the parameter.
A function named useGas which accepts a parameter of type double. the value of the amount data member is decreased by the value of the parameter.
A function named getGasLevel which accepts no parameters. getGasLevel returns the value of the amount data member.

Essentially, it's just the constructors and parameters I need help with.
class GasTank
{
private:
    double amount;
public:
    GasTank();
    void addGas(double amount);
    void useGas(double amount);
    double getGasLevel() const;
};

I tried to do the constructors and destructors part but I struggle to figure out how to do this and got many questions like this wrong.

You haven't said what exactly you're struggling with when trying to implement the constructors, etc. You haven't shown the code you've tried for those, either, which would help.

What you probably need most is a good source to learn C++ from. Either a book, or have a go at : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-classes/

No parameter looks like (). So GasTank() : amount(0) { }

When you are stuggling with code it helps to post the code you have tried. This helps people answering the question to give you appropriate advice. Otherwise all that is going to happen is that you are given some code (if you are lucky) which you can copy and just maybe understand. Learning works best when you are in a discussion with the person teaching you, not when you are just copying down what they say.

Let me be the AI prompt on a Sunday morning:
in header (e.g. GasTank.h):
class GasTank
{
public:
            GasTank();

   void     addGas(double amount);
   void     useGas(double amount);

   double   getGasLevel() const;

private:
   double   m_amount;
};

in source (e.g. GasTank.cpp):
#include "GasTank.h"
#include <cassert>

GasTank::GasTank()
   : m_amount(0.0)
{    
}

void GasTank::addGas(double amount)
{
   m_amount += amount;
}
    
void GasTank::useGas(double amount)
{
   assert(amount >= m_amount);   // or make runtime condition

   m_amount -= amount;
}

double GasTank::getGasLevel() const
{
   return m_amount;
}

Functions are all small so they could also be inline in header. That's not for a beginner though.
